# apply binding correction to titlepage

Tags: titles, koma-script, classicthesis

i am using the [arsclassica](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arsclassica?) package, documentclass `scrreprt` with the options `oneside` and `BCOR10mm`. however, the binding correction does not apply to the titlepage as can be seen in the package example. is there a way to make that happen?

Comment: Please post a [compilable minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html). Please also load package `showframe` and use *extreme* values for `BCOR`. Additionally, are you using package `geometry`? An MWE will show.

Comment: One additional thing: `BCOR10mm` is deprecated. Make it `BCOR=10mm` or better `BCOR=50mm`  to really see a difference.

Comment: a working example is directly given by the link above, it is compilable expect for the bibliography and index. i fear something is going to get lost when i create my own working example :/ the `geometry` package is not loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example shows that binding correction also applies to the titlepage.

```
\documentclass[
  oneside,
  headinclude,
  footinclude,
  titlepage,
  BCOR=30mm
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

With `BCOR=0mm` the result would be:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. then the behaviour i encountered may be due to the explicit titlepage template from the arsclassica package :/

Comment: As @Johannes_B already has said: Post a MWE that shows the issue. The link in your question is only the CTAN entry of the package. There is neither an example *directly* available nor an explicit titlepage template.

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, i will be more precise the next time.

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out above, the problem is due to the titlepage template in the arsclassica package. commenting out the line

```
\changetext{}{}{}{((\paperwidth  - \textwidth) / 2) - \oddsidemargin - \hoffset - 1in}{}
```

finally did it.